# Nested SELECT Issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am having a small issue with SqlServerCe.
When using the below sqlString to perform a ExecuteNonQuery(); command I get the error below.

```
string sqlString = "INSERT INTO Images (UID, Name) " +
            "VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM Contributors WHERE ID = @UID), @Name);";
```

gives this error:

```
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 41,Token in error = SELECT ]
```

Any suggestions?

## Method

```
public static void InsertImage(Contributor contObj, string ImageName)
{
    string sqlString = "INSERT INTO Images (UID, Name) " +
        "VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM [Contributors] WHERE ID = @UID), @Name);";
    using (SqlCeConnection sqlConnection =
        new SqlCeConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCeCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCeCommand(sqlString, sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", contObj.ID);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ImageName);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will want to use `INSERT INTO...SELECT..FROM`

```
string sqlString = "INSERT INTO Images (UID, Name) " +
            "SELECT ID, @Name FROM Contributors WHERE ID = @UID;";
```

If you already knew the value for `@ID`, then you could use the `INSERT INTO... VALUES...` query

```
INSERT INTO Images (UID, Name)
VALUES (@UID, @Name)
```

Edit, here is your code with the update query

```
public static void InsertImage(Contributor contObj, string ImageName)
{
    string sqlString = "INSERT INTO Images (UID, Name) " +
        "VALUES (@UID, @Name)";
    using (SqlCeConnection sqlConnection =
        new SqlCeConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCeCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCeCommand(sqlString, sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", contObj.ID);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ImageName);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Name is not in Contributors. There's a foreign key relationship between Images.UID and Contributors.ID

Comment: I think you might need the keyword VALUES.

Comment: since you are using a parameter, you will need to tell it the @Name value when you execute it. can you edit your question post your full code? then I can show you.

Comment: @user1027620 I updated my answer, since you are passing in the name parameter it doesn't matter if it doesn't exist in that table you are providing the value

Comment: bluefeet, I'm getting this -> A parameter is not allowed in this location. Ensure that the '@' sign is in a valid location or that parameters are valid at all in this SQL statement.

Comment: @user1027620 updated my answer, you can use the INSERT VALUES since you don't need to use the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using a nested select here? Since `@UID` already references the ID column that you're selecting, can't you just do:

```
INSERT INTO Images (UID, Name) 
VALUES (@UID, @Name)
```

If you really MUST use a select, then take a look at bluefeet's answer. He's supplying the param that you specified (`@Name`) as one of the values being inserted, so its OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way instead:

```
string sqlString = @"INSERT INTO Images(UID, Name)
                     SELECT ID, @Name
                     FROM Contributors
                     WHERE ID = @UID"
```